# Is there a way to compare more than one value of dataset against a single value of another dataset in left outer join(Flink)

Tags: apache-flink, outer-join

I am trying to find out a way to check whether two values of a dataset can be checked against one value of another dataset using Flink Left Outer Join?

```
    final DataSet<type> finalDataSet = dataSet1
            .leftOuterJoin(dataSet2)
            .where("value1")
            .equalTo("value2")
            .with(new FunctionNameToBeImplemented())
            .name("StepName");
```

This works fine for a one to one check.

Can there be a way to do something similar:

```
      final DataSet<type> finalDataSet = dataSet1
            .leftOuterJoin(dataSet2)
            .where(["value1","value2"]) // List of values
            .contains("value2")
            .with(new FunctionNameToBeImplemented())
            .name("StepName");
```

I expect the output to check value1 and then value2 and if any (or both) matches, pass it to the function "FunctionNameToBeImplemented()" for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

The outer join in Flink's DataSet API are strictly equality joins.

You can implement your use case with two separate joins and union the result. In order to avoid duplicates, on of the join functions should check if the other condition applies as well and only produce a result if it does not.

```
left  -\
        > JOIN(l.val1 == r.val2)[emit result] ---------------------\
right -/                                                            \
                                                                     > UNION
left  -\                                                            /
        > JOIN(l.val2 == r.val2)[emit result if l.val1 != r.val2) -/
right -/
```